# When I print my output there is always a "5" appear, even though I avoid entering "5" from the beginning

Tags: c++

For some reason, my output for sorted integers always has this "5" in it, even if I didn't enter "5" to my input, it still appears. And I am curious where does this "5" came from because when I changed the n1 to 4, the sorted output just went crazy, the n[0] is always 1446864 or something like that.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//The first new function template should allow the user to enter the array data from the keyboard.
template <class T>
void enterdata (T *a, const int n)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        cin>> a[i];
} 

template <class T>
void printdata(T *a, const int n)
{
    for (int i=0;i<n;i++)
    cout<<a[i]<<" ";
    cout<<endl;
}
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//The second new function template should print the average of the array with the two largest values 
//excluded from the average calculation.
template <class T>
void sorting(T *a, const int n)
{
    for (int j=0; j<n; j++)
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) 
  {
        if (a[i] < a[i+1] ) 
        {
            float temp;
            temp=a[i];
            a[i]=a[i+1];
            a[i+1]=temp;
        }
  }
}
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//The third new function template should sort the array data in ascending order. 
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//The fourth new function template should save the array data to a text file.
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//The fifth new function template should retrieve the array data from the text file.
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
int main()
{
    const int n1 = 5, n2 = 7, n3 = 5;
    int a[n1];
    float b[n2];
    char c[n3];
    /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    cout <<"enter 5 integers" << endl;
    enterdata(a, n1);
    cout <<"enter 7 decimals" << endl;
    enterdata(b,n2);
    cout <<"enter 5 letters" << endl;
    enterdata(c,n3);
    //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    cout<<"\nThe 5 integers: ";
    printdata(a,n1);
    cout<<"The 7 decimals: ";
    printdata(b,n2);
    cout<<"The 5 letters: ";
    printdata(c,n3);
    cout<<"Testing/////////////////////////////////////////////////////"<<endl;
    sorting(a,n1);
    sorting(b,n2);
    sorting(c,n3);
    cout<<"sorted inetgers: ";
    printdata(a,n1);
    cout<<"sorted decimals: ";
    printdata(b,n2);
    cout<<"sorted letters: ";
    printdata(c,n3);
    return 0;
}
/*
enter 5 integers
1
9
4
8
7
enter 7 decimals
2.1
6
5
69
4
8
5
enter 5 letters
hello
The 5 integers: 1 9 4 8 7
The 7 decimals: 2.1 6 5 69 4 8 5
The 5 letters: h e l l o
Testing/////////////////////////////////////////////////////
sorted inetgers: 9 8 7 5 4
sorted decimals: 69 8 6 5 5 4 2.1
sorted letters: o l l h e
Press any key to continue . . .
*/
```

Comment: This is wrong `if (a[i] < a[i+1])`, `i` can be `n-1` and `a[n]` is out of bounds. The loop should probably stop before then `i < n-1`.

Comment: `float temp` is strange, a `T temp` would be better. Even better: why not use `std::swap` instead of implementing the swap by hand?

Comment: @WernerHenze, my professor told us to use "const int n1 = 5; int a[n1]; - eerorika" for now, since we will go over swap in later lessons. And I am new to C++ with some C experience, so I am still trying to figure everything out. But I will definitely look up swap when I am done with the current homework.